# How to make DateTimePicker close when a date is selected, Im using Mahpps.Metro?

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I'm using MahApps.Metro.Controls DateTimePicker, everything is working fine except that the datetime popup doesn't close when a date is selected. Is there a way to enable this. I have gone through some of the documentation but haven't found such a setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any property that you can set set to get this behaviour, but you could handle the `SelectedDateTimeChanged` event:

```
private void DateTimePicker_SelectedDateTimeChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<DateTime?> e) =>
    ((MahApps.Metro.Controls.DateTimePicker)sender).IsDropDownOpen = false;
```